# Kubernates with custom database

Tags: kubernetes

In Kubernates, heapster and influxdb is present with thier specific schema. I want to store pod all information in a custom database (sqlite) with my specified schema. Is it possible? If it is possible, what is the source of information for pod? How can I take it and store?

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes uses etcd to store metadata about the cluster. etcd is a schemaless key-value store. Storage of cluster objects uses an object serialization scheme.

The code to read starts here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/2bb1e7581544b9bd059eafe6ac29775332e5a1d6/staging/src/k8s.io/apiserver/pkg/storage

Comment: I am very new to kubernetes and also in go program.I have a query.can i get cpu usage memory and network usage of all running pod with time from etcd?